# where to find Terminal log history with commands and it's results?

Tags: 12.04, command-line, log, bash-history

I tried to install **Yocto project** in **Ubuntu 12.04**, when for the first time i got few warnings, and i gave a rerun then i got some other warnings in the terminal.

Now, my terminal is exceeded it's limit(guess **500** lines)and I would like to see those warnings but they are not visible in terminal anymore.

I tried to see in the bash history **~/.bash_history**, but unfortunately only command history is available there.

Please help to see complete log where i can find the writeback data after entering commands & also how can i increase no. of lines?. (i am quite new with Ubuntu).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Please help to see complete log where i can find the writeback data after entering command

Nowhere.

> also how can i increase no. of lines?.

gnome-terminal See edit > profiles > edit > tab scrolling

[image]

Comment: Thanks @rinzwind :) though first part is not possible to reproduce, i can able to trace yocto project log file, second part helped me, especially the image (i use ubuntu in different language,so) i set it up to 10k lines :)